# how to implement code completion in qt

Tags: c++, qt, ide, autocomplete

i am writing an ide using qt (on c++) and i need to add auto completion feature to it

so i want to know :

how to do that (i am using `qtPlainTextEdit`) ?

what the data structure i should use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should take a look at this:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html

I used this example to understand CodeCompletion and I think it is fine :)

[edit]
Qt has a own class for such purpose called QCompleter: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html

Comment: Above link is broken. Current active link - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html

Answer (score 3):

I also need to write a code completer in `Qt` and the first link Tobias provided is the document to look at. It is comprehensive and clear and worked for me. I am sure will work for you.

If you need a code completer in lineEdit, it's pretty simple (from the [QCompleter](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qcompleter.html) documentation):

```
QStringList wordList;
wordList << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five";
QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

However a QPlainTextEdit, or QTextEdit don't have a built-in setCompleter() member function so you must follow the [custom code completer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/tools-customcompleter.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

That's a big, complex feature. I'd look at how it's been done in [the Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools).